# Any advantage to keep an auto-incrementing field in addition to guid

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following db table:

```
`users`
- guid (UUID)
- username
- creation_data
```

Is there any advantage in keeping an auto-incrementing field here as well?

```
`users`
- id (autoincrement)
- guid
- username
- creation_date
```

Perhaps it would make foreign-keying to the table more efficient or something else? What would be the pros and cons of keeping both fields (id & guid) vs only one (guid)?

Comment: Yes, it would make foreign keys more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to get rid of UUID field and use only:

```
`users`
- id (autoincrement)
- username
- creation_date
```

This way all the foreign keys and indexes will work times faster since all computations and comparisons  will be done using a integer instead of strings.

As a rough estimate you can assume that integer comparison requires single CPU cycle and comparing string with 20 chars will require 20 cycles.

Comment: My guess is *guid* is necessary in this application (since, other guess, `id >= guid` and not necessary equal)

Comment: @Anton Milkov, there's no need to compare strings. UUID represented as 128 bit, not 20 chars string. It's indeed larger than an Integer but the performance penalty is negligible

Answer (score 0):

Adding auto increment id:

Advantages

- None, unless you need to know the items insertion order.

Disadvantages

- More disk space
- If you're going to add an index - bigger indexes (more memory usage, disk space)
- If you're going to set up a replication you will encounter problems (some problems you might encounter are listed here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-features-auto-increment.html)